# How to print an unsigned int* in c?

Tags: c, printing, unsigned-integer

I tried to print an `unsigned int*` in C. I used `%X` but the compiler said:

> " format `%x` expects argument of type `unsigned int`, but argument 3 has type `unsigned int*` ".

I also used `"%u"` but I got the same error again.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Compiler is telling 100% correct. Use `%p` format specifier to print the pointer type variable. For e.g `unsigned int *ptr = &someAddr; printf("Address %p\n", (void*)ptr);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print a pointer, you need to use `%p` format specifier and cast the argument to `void *`. Something like

```
 printf ("%p", (void *)x);
```

where `x` is of type `unsigned int*`.

However, if you want to print the value stored at `x`, you need to dereference that, like

```
printf ("%u", *x);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the pointer itself you should use the format `%p`:

```
// Create a pointer and make it point somewhere
unsigned int *pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer);

// Print the pointer (note the cast)
printf("pointer is %p\n", (void *) pointer);
```

Or if you want to print the value that the pointer is pointing to, then you need to dereference the pointer:

```
// Create a pointer and make it point somewhere
unsigned int *pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer);

// Set the value
*pointer = 0x12345678;

// And print the value
printf("value at pointer is %08X\n", *pointer);
```

While the `%p` format specifier is uncommon, most decent books, classes and tutorials should have information about dereferencing pointers to get the value.

I also recommend e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) which lists all standard format specifiers and possible modifiers.